# How to convert a single-select parameter into multiple filter values in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I've built a matrix that summarizes records from multiple departments into department groups.  I'm trying to build a drill-down report.  I'm having trouble trying to convert the department group name passed as a parameter to the drill-down into the individual department numbers that make up the group.

Using SQL Server 2012 w/MS Report Builder 3.0.

Tried using a CASE statement in the WHERE clause to return the department numbers associated with the department group name passed in the parameter.  This works for department groups that contain a single department number, but errors whenever the department group contains more than one department.

This code works for single-department department groups, but fails when the case statement includes the multi-department groups.

```
NPD.ACT_DEPTARTMENT IN (CASE
WHEN @DEPT = 'Business Group' THEN ('40', '43', '45', '46', '47', '83', '84', '85', '86', '87', '89', '90')
WHEN @DEPT = 'Chemistry Group' THEN ('06', '07')
WHEN @DEPT = 'Emergency Prep' THEN ('33')
WHEN @DEPT = 'Engineering Group' THEN ('60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72')
WHEN @DEPT = 'Maintain Group' THEN ('21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '76', '78')
WHEN @DEPT = 'Management Group' THEN ('36', '48', '80', '81', '88', '96')
WHEN @DEPT = 'Operations Group' THEN ('11', '12', '13')
WHEN @DEPT = 'Projects Group' THEN ('54', '73', '79')
WHEN @DEPT = 'Security' THEN ('34')
WHEN @DEPT = 'Supply Group' THEN ('50', '98')
WHEN @DEPT = 'Training Group' THEN ('82', '91', '92', '93', '94', '95')
END)
```

Originally tried this code, but couldn't get any of it to work.  Googling indicated I was trying to get the CASE to execute code, rather than just returning part of the `"IN"` expression.

```
AND CASE WHEN @DEPT = 'Business Group' THEN NPD_ACT.DEPARTMENT IN ('40', '43', '45', '46', '47', '83', '84', '85', '86', '87', '89', '90')
WHEN @DEPT = 'Chemistry Group' THEN NPD_ACT.DEPARTMENT IN ('06', '07')
WHEN @DEPT = 'Emergency Prep' THEN NPD_ACT.DEPARTMENT IN ('33')
WHEN @DEPT = 'Engineering Group' THEN NPD_ACT.DEPARTMENT IN ('60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72')
WHEN @DEPT = 'Maintain Group' THEN NPD_ACT.DEPARTMENT IN ('21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '76', '78')
WHEN @DEPT = 'Management Group' THEN NPD_ACT.DEPARTMENT IN ('36', '48', '80', '81', '88', '96')
WHEN @DEPT = 'Operations Group' THEN NPD_ACT.DEPARTMENT IN ('11', '12', '13')
WHEN @DEPT = 'Security' THEN NPD_ACT.DEPARTMENT IN ('34')
WHEN @DEPT = 'Supply Group' THEN NPD_ACT.DEPARTMENT IN ('50', '98')
WHEN @DEPT = 'Training Group' THEN NPD_ACT.DEPARTMENT IN ('82', '91', '92', '93', '94', '95')
END
```

Error returned is

> "Incorrect syntax near ','."

The error is returned for the first line of the CASE statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `@DEPT` contains only one department name:

You'll need to switch around what is inside/outside of the case statement.

```
@DEPT = (CASE WHEN NPD.ACT_DEPTARTMENT IN ('40', '43', '45', '46', '47', '83', '84', '85', '86', '87', '89', '90') THEN 'Business Group'
              WHEN NPD.ACT_DEPTARTMENT IN ('06', '07') THEN 'Chemistry Group'
              WHEN NPD.ACT_DEPTARTMENT IN ('33') THEN 'Emergency Prep'
              WHEN NPD.ACT_DEPTARTMENT IN ('60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72') THEN 'Engineering Group'
              WHEN NPD.ACT_DEPTARTMENT IN ('21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '76', '78') THEN 'Maintain Group'
              WHEN NPD.ACT_DEPTARTMENT IN ('36', '48', '80', '81', '88', '96') THEN 'Management Group'
              WHEN NPD.ACT_DEPTARTMENT IN ('11', '12', '13') THEN 'Operations Group'
              WHEN NPD.ACT_DEPTARTMENT IN ('54', '73', '79') THEN 'Projects Group'
              WHEN NPD.ACT_DEPTARTMENT IN ('34') THEN 'Security'
              WHEN NPD.ACT_DEPTARTMENT IN ('50', '98') THEN 'Supply Group'
              WHEN NPD.ACT_DEPTARTMENT IN ('82', '91', '92', '93', '94', '95') THEN 'Training Group'
         END)
```

This could honestly use a translation table with the Department Group, and the Department Numbers.

Comment: Eureka!  I'm having a tough time following the logic flow of WHY this works (it seems counter-intuitive to me), but I can't argue with the results.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Your case statement has to return a single value.  You can't use a list of values for a single THEN.  You're essentially just reversing the expression so that the case statement only returns one value.